# Count occurrences of string "<1" in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of numbers with some entered as the text string "<1" (w/o quotes).

I want to count the number of occurrences of the string "<1" in this column.

```
=COUNTIF(range,"*~<1")
```

appears to work, but

```
=COUNTIF(range,"~<1")
```

does not.

I understand the need for the `~` to interpret the `<` as a text char, but why does it need the `*`?

Comment: Are you trying to see if they're less than the number 1? Is the string aspect required, because you can do `=COUNTIF(range,"<1")`.  Also, your `"*~<1"` works correctly, i.e. counting numbers less than 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde is only used to escape the `?`, the `*` and the `~`. If you need to escape the operator, put an `=` at the beginning:

```
=COUNTIF(range, "=<1")
```

It works with the asterisk because that pushes the `<` out of the beginning, operator position where it becomes a regular character. Notice that works even without the `~`.

Excel seems to expect the first character(s) to either be a comparison operator or a literal character, including the `~`, unless followed by `*` or `?` but not the `*` or `?`. After that, a misplaced `~` is simply ignored.

Comment: Great response. As I am looking for the exact string "<1", using the suggested "=<1" worked even better than the working solution that I had.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing out the tilde `~`:

```
=COUNTIF(A1,"~<1")
<1    Result: 0
`<1   Result: 0
~<1   Result: 1

=COUNTIF(A1,"~-1")
-1    Result: 0
`-1   Result: 0
=-1   Result: 0
~-1   Result: 1

=COUNTIF(A1,"*~<")
foo<  Result: 1
foo~< Result: 1

=COUNTIF(A1,"<")
<     Result: 0
~<    Result: 0

=COUNTIF(A1,"~<")
<     Result: 0
~<    Result: 1

=COUNTIF(A1,"*<")
<     Result: 1
~<    Result: 1
```

The issue is that the `<` symbol in the formula is considered to be different than the `<` symbol in the cell value.  Therefore, only the text version of `<` is considered as a match.